# Type 'U | (U & Partial<T>)' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>' when T extends U

Tags: typescript, generics

In my code I make use of generics and `Partial`. There is one case where I want to be sure that the `Partial` object contains a specific property. This property is also a constraint for the generic type that is used by the method.

For me this is valid TypeScript code but the compiler complains:

```
Type '{ id: -1; } | ({ id: -1; } & Partial<T>)' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
   Type '{ id: -1; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.(2322)
```

Following the code and the [example in TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKomARwK4oN7LAAmAXMiNgLYBG0yAvgNwBQzCANnAM5fIBiAewEAeACrIIAD0ggivdFlwA%20ZHmbINyanCgAKAdQBWZAAo6wwOOzEqAPuWzt2ASlPnL10SrWbfyKBBg2FAgqoSkyAC0AIwANMgAdEkGhkzqmvTM9EA)

```
interface Unique { id: number };

class Foo<T extends Unique> {
    bar(obj: Partial<T> | null): Partial<T> {
        return { id: -1, ...obj};
    }
}
```

Why the compiler complains? How would you refactor the code without casting?

Comment: It complains because you can extend types by narrowing properties like [this](https://tsplay.dev/AwQ2vN).

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, the example is very informative.